# PHP For-loop for Post array

Tags: php, syntax-error

So I have a dynamic table on the page 2 where the user can add as many entries as they want. After submitting the 3 page is getting all the info just fine. The problem is my for-loop iteration through the array is not working. Here's the code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_POST["fname_new"]); $i++) {
    $fname_new = $_POST["fname_new"][i];
    $lname_new = $_POST["lname_new"][i];
    $phone_new = $_POST["phone_new"][i];
    $email_new = $_POST["email_new"][i];
    $ethnicity_new = $_POST["ethnicity_new"][i];
    $stmt = $link -> prepare("INSERT INTO Conference (`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Phone`, `Email`, `Ethnicity`) VALUES (:first_new, :last_new, :phone_new, :email_new, :ethnicity_new)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':first_new', $fname_new);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last_new', $lname_new);
    $stmt->bindParam(':phone_new', $phone_new);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email_new', $email_new);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ethnicity_new', $ethnicity_new);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

So when I do

```
echo sizeof($_POST["fname_new"]);
```

It shows me the correct number, so if there were 3 rows that the user added on page 2 then the value echoed should be 3, which it is. When I do:

```
echo $_POST["fname_new"][0];
```

Then it appropriately gives the first name from the first row. I can replace 0 with any number, as long as it is in bounds, and it is correct. But for some reason when I do

```
echo $_POST["fname_new"][i];
```

It doesn't print anything. I have no idea why this for loop isn't working. Logically it is correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the $ to point to the variable i

Try this:

```
echo $_POST["fname_new"][$i];
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides all the answers given, you are missing the point with *prepared queries*. You prepare a query **once**, and **use it many** times.

So:

```
  $stmt = $link -> prepare(
     "INSERT INTO Conference (`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Phone`, `Email`, `Ethnicity`)
      VALUES (:first_new, :last_new, :phone_new, :email_new, :ethnicity_new)");
```

should be outside of the loop!

Comment: what about the binds? Can those be outside as well?

Comment: In this situation they could. For clarity I leave them inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `$`:

```
$fname_new = $_POST["fname_new"][$i];
$lname_new = $_POST["lname_new"][$i];
$phone_new = $_POST["phone_new"][$i];
$email_new = $_POST["email_new"][$i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
$_POST["fname_new"][$i];
```

Your passing the literal 'i' (most likely, depends on PHP version) rather than variable $i. So it will be trying to return the value with the key index of 'i', which is not set.